# Python ctypes breaks on include iostream

Tags: python, c++, windows, ctypes

I am using python ctypes to call a function in c++ from python. Currently, I have the following c++ file:

**five.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    int get_five(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And python file:

**five.py**

```
import ctypes
from pathlib import Path


lib = ctypes.CDLL(Path(Path.cwd(),'five.dll').as_posix())
print(lib.get_five())
```

Which works and prints the number 5 when i run it.

However, as soon as I include any headers in the c++ file, it breaks down. So if I change the file to:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    int get_five(){
        return 5;
    }
}
```

It breaks, and I get the following error:

*FileNotFoundError: Could not find module '...\five.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.*

I am compiling on Windows, with the following command:

```
g++ -shared five.cpp -o five.dll
```

I am probably missing something obvious, since I am very new to programming in c++. However, I can't seem to find what it is.

Comment: When you use [*dependency walker*](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your `five.dll`, you will see some DLL dependencies.  Are those DLL files located in a place where the loader will find them?

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for the comment. I downloaded the dependency walker, but when i run it on five.dll it just freezes.

Comment: @Eljay After some time, it gives a result and the following errors:
"Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: A circular dependency was detected.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module." However, this also happens when i remove the #include <iostream>

Comment: Puzzling.  I'm not currently set up to be able to reproduce the environment.  Possibly, DLL has evolved beyond what *dependency walker* can handle.  (Which would make me sad, because it's been a very useful tool for me.)

Comment: The c++ runtime DLL isn’t being found.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm not sure what you mean with this, probably due to my lack of C++ experience. The .dll file is in the same location though, and it seems to work as long as i don't include iostream.

Comment: Your DLL is dynamically linking to the C++ runtime DLL due to including iostream.h.  That DLL isn't found in the DLL search path.  Try using `-static` when building your DLL.

Comment: @Tolonen That did it. Thanks a lot! If you want to post your comment as an answer, ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be this by Mark Tolonen:

> Your DLL is dynamically linking to the C++ runtime DLL due to including iostream.h. That DLL isn't found in the DLL search path. Try using `-static` when building your DLL.